# PowerShell error: "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression."

Tags: powershell, error-handling, null, vmware

Here is the script for reference - it is failing at the below line and I'm not sure why:

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\users\jk\documents\jk.ps1:19 char:45
 ... -VMhost | %{$_.ExtensionData.UpdateProductLockerLocation($datastore)} ...                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

Script:

```
Set-PowerCLIConfiguration -InvalidCertificateAction Ignore -Confirm:$false
# VMware VirtualCenter server name 
$VCserver = Read-Host "Enter the vCenter server name"

# Connect to the vCenter server 
Connect-VIServer -server $VCserver

# variable
$cluster = 'cluster01'
$hosts = Get-Cluster -Name $cluster | Get-VMHost
$datastore = '/vmfs/volumes/04c62043-2d22f726/vmwtools/VMware Tools 12.0.6/'

# Display the current VMware Tools location
# default is: /locker/packages/vmtoolsRepo/
$hosts | Get-AdvancedSetting -Name "UserVars.ProductLockerLocation" | Select-Object Entity, Value

# Change the VMware Tools location
Get-cluster -name $cluster | Get-VMhost | %{$_.ExtensionData.UpdateProductLockerLocation($datastore)}  

# Display current VMware Location
$hosts | Get-AdvancedSetting -Name "UserVars.ProductLockerLocation" | Select-Object Entity,Value

# Disconnect from vCenter 
Disconnect-VIserver -server * -Confirm:$false
```

Comment: The answer is in the error message.  It is telling you that the property `ExtensionData` is null.  If this is legitimate (i.e. if there is a valid reason why `ExtensionData` isn't always populated), you will have to add an `if` statement to check for that and only call `UpdateProductLockerLocation` when you have a valid object.  If it is not meant to be null, then you need to see why `Get-VMhost` isn't properly returning the data.

Comment: thanks for the reply but what does this mean in the context of the script? do i need to change something? I am following this guide for ref:

https://www.ivobeerens.nl/2021/07/08/create-a-central-vmware-tools-repository/?utm_source=rss&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=create-a-central-vmware-tools-repository

Comment: @powershell_noob Yes, you have to make the changes suggested by boxdog.

Comment: where do i add the IF statement in the script, please? sorry im new to powershell

Comment: Get-VMHost returns data - so this is not the issue?


-PS C:\users\jk\documents> Get-VMHost

Name                 ConnectionState PowerState NumCpu CpuUsageMhz CpuTotalMhz   MemoryUsageGB   MemoryTotalGB Version
----                 --------------- ---------- ------ ----------- -----------   -------------   ------------- -------
host1... Connected       PoweredOn      28       41839       72688         275.204         767.873   6.7.0
host2... Connected       PoweredOn      12        9643       31992          98.688         143.990   6.7.0

Answer (score 1):

As the wording of the error message suggests ("You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression."), you tried to call a method on an expression that is effectively `$null`, which in your case is `$_.ExtensionData`.

If that expression is *expected* to be *situationally* `$null` in your [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) (`%`) call, you can simply *avoid calling the method* whenever you find the expression value to be `$null`:

In **PowerShell (Core) 7.1 and above**, you can use the [null-conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#null-conditional-operators--and-), **`?.`**:

```
# PS v7.1+
# Note the use of ?. instead of .
Get-cluster -name $cluster | Get-VMhost |
  ForEach-Object { $_.ExtensionData?.UpdateProductLockerLocation($datastore) }
```

As a **general caveat**:

- While `?.` works as expected with *properties*, with *variables* it unfortunately and unexpectedly requires the variable name to be enclosed in `{...}`, because - surprisingly - `?` is a legal character in a variable name.
- For instance, `Set-StrictMode -Version 2; $foo = $null; ${foo}?.ToUpper()` works, but using `$foo?.ToUpper()` instead does *not*, because PowerShell looks for a variable named `$foo?` (sic), which doesn't exist. Requesting that this counterintuitive behavior be changed - even though it is *technically* a breaking change - is the subject of [GitHub issue #14025](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14025).

---

In **Windows PowerShell** you can use an [`if`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_If) statement:

```
Get-cluster -name $cluster | Get-VMhost |
  ForEach-Object { 
    if ($null -ne $_.ExtensionData)  { 
      $_.ExtensionData.UpdateProductLockerLocation($datastore) 
    } 
  }
```

Note how `$null` is placed on the *LHS* (left-hand side) of the `-ne` operation above (applies equally to `-eq`), which is a good habit to form, because it is the only fully reliable way to test for `$null` - see [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-eq-and--ne).